# About VSC, it doesn't work well(Python, windows)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

When I run python code in the VSC, there's a problem.

- When I initially run `shift+enter` to run each code in a particular line, it works well. However, after then that, when I try to run the overall code by using triangle button, there's a problem.
- Same as the above, when I initially run the overall code by using triangle button, then I can't run each of code in one line with `shift+enter`

ex.1) When I use loop code like 'for i in range~..', the loop code works well. But when trying to do it by running the overall code, it doesn't work(specially, terminal shows that there's an indentation error.
2x.2) When I call some files on my C drive, I can call it by using `shift+enter` to run each code. And when I try to do it by using triangle code to make it, it doesn't work with error(invalid syntax).

(result with using shift+enter to call files)

```py
import os
file_path = os.path.join('enron1/ham/0007.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt')
```

```
(result with running overall codes)
    & C:/Users/gram/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/gram/Desktop/강의/기계학습/Practice/test.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/gram/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/gram/Desktop/강의/기계학습/Practice/test.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(reference)
I re-installed VSC and other python files(Anaconda3) to fix this problem, it was useless.

Comment: Can you share the code complete code?

Comment: naming your file just `test` is a bad practice and can lead to funny behavior, there is always a system command named `test` or it could be a build in module

Answer (score 0):

> > > File "", line 1
> > > first you need to get out from the this triangle line(>>>) by write >>>ctrl+z
> > > then you can run your entire code .

Comment: I truly understood what you pointed.
Then can you explain about this case? I used 'shift+enter' to run each of codes, it occurs error like this.

""
import os
file_path = 'enron1/ham/0007.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
    ham_sample = infile.read()  
""

Then it occurs

""
>>> with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'with' statement on line 1
""

There's no problem about my indentation..

Comment: could you please just give your code to get this error clearly

Comment: Thanks, it's just all.
(code)
file_path = 'enron1/ham/0007.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:    
    ham_sample = infile.read()  # indentation error
(error)
  File "c:\Users\gram\Desktop\강의\기계학습\Practice\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'enron1/ham/0007.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.tx